# How do I force a browser to read updated database information?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Apologies if this question has been answered before, but I'm not sure how to easily describe it...

I'm programming a system with PHP and MySql that will allow users that are logged in to build a sports team. I have system set up where a user "bids" on a player, and that player is added to their roster. The code that writes to the database is very simple and works fine:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE bidpool SET BidExpires='$newbidexpires' WHERE Player='$player'");
mysql_query("UPDATE bidpool SET CurrentBid='$bid' WHERE Player='$player'");
mysql_query("UPDATE bidpool SET TeamName='$NewTeamName' WHERE Player='$player'");
```

When I check the database, that information is entered correctly.

When I load up another page, where the team's updated roster is located, this is the code I use:

```
echo "<table>";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bidpool WHERE TeamName='$teamname'");

$playerbid = 0;
$i = 0;

$num = mysql_numrows($result);

while ($i < $num) {

    $playerroster = mysql_result($result, $i, "Player");
    $playerbid = mysql_result($result, $i, "CurrentBid");
    $playerexpires = mysql_result($result, $i, "BidExpires");

    IF ($time > $playerexpires) {

        $playerexpires = "BID WON";
    }

    echo "<tr> 
                    <td width='30%'>$playerroster</td>
                    <td width='30%'>$playerbid</td>
                    <td width='30%'>$playerexpires</td>
                    </tr>";
    $i++;
}
echo "</table">;
```

The problem? Everything writes to the database just fine when there is a new bid. When I load the roster page up in Firefox, it shows the roster as it is in the database, with even the most recent changes shown only seconds later.

When I load it in Safari and Chrome, however, it shows an old version of the roster. Even after I clear the browser cache, reset the browser, and even reboot my computer, it still shows an old version from the database.

This type of system, with multiple users bidding on players over the course of several days, requires that players see the most recent bids and their recent roster changes as soon as possible. But it won't work if the browser won't cooperate.

If it makes any difference, the site is run on WordPress.

What do you think I'm doing wrong here? Why does this system work flawlessly in one browser, but not another?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: May I ask you if you aren't loading another local version of your website ? Because everything here is server-sided, which is really disturbing with the problem you explained.

Comment: Any chance you have a WordPress caching plugin?

Comment: odd, are you sure wordpress is not caching?

Comment: I do often work with a local version of the site, but everything here is connected to the live site. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Does it show the old version in Chrome's incognito window too?

Comment: @Shoan +1 Good Cache test

Comment: Yes, it shows the old version in Chrome's incognito window. It works just the same as the normal Chrome window.

Comment: wordpress cache...gotta be...that or your URL is wrong (pointing to a static version or something).  These are server side things...so the issue is either a cache somewhere or you are not comparing apples to apples...

Comment: there are other potential caches, firewall, ISP, but yup wordpress most likley

Comment: re. Chrome incognito: the *first* time you load the page in a new 'incognito' page, do you have the new version? From the 2nd load, 'incognito' keeps the environment until you close the tabs/browser, and it is normal to behave like normal Chrome..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is certainly a caching problem; you can test whether it's a client or Wordpress issue by inserting some extra URL parameters.

Try hitting the page with ?extraRandomParameter=changeThisValueEachTime.

If that works, it's a client thing; otherwise, you'll have to investigate more specifically as to how Wordpress caches (and how to get around it).